# $G$ a Lie group with a $K$-bi-invariant metric for a closed Lie subgroup $K\subset G$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $K$ be a closed (connected if needed) Lie subgroup of $G$. Equip $G$ with a metric that is $G$-left-invariant and $K$-right-invariant. If $X_\mathfrak{k},Y_{\mathfrak{k}}\in\mathfrak{k}\subset\mathfrak{g}$ are such that $[X_{\mathfrak{k}},Y_{\mathfrak{k}}]=0$ then can we say that $X_{\mathfrak{k}}$ and $Y_{\mathfrak{k}}$ are linearlly dependent (as $K$'s inherited metric is bi-invariant and so it has positive sectional curvature)?

Comment: Would this be the case with $G = SU(3)$ and $K$ the subgroup of diagonal matrices?

Comment: A generic group.

Comment: I understand that you're asking this for a generic Lie group, but I'm asking you to verify it for this case.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this case seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: But $SU(n)$ is compact and the diagonal matrices are not

Comment: If you mean the diagonal matrices in $SU(3)$, this group is discrete, so its Lie algebra is trivial.

Comment: Diagonal matrices in $SU(3)$, but not necessarily multiples of the identity.  The center is discrete, but the maximal torus has dimension two.

Comment: Oh, I see. I forgot to ask $K$ to have positive curvature. But in this case the answer to my question is clearly yes.